# java : better way of doing this than using if and else

Tags: java

I have a requirement were  depending on a  particular key value of a map , i need to format the output .

For example if its value greater than  1 then  needed to display only 2 decimal points after the value 
(12.23) or else if its value is less than 1 , i need to show 4 decimal points after it .

I have written the code its working fine , but i am looking for a better way of doing this  (basically i didn't liked if else conditions in my  code )

This is my program where depending on the last attribute key value i am formatting the output

```
package com;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class CustValues {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Map valuesMap = new HashMap();

        valuesMap.put("mktCap", "12.4d");
        valuesMap.put("last", "0.4344");
        valuesMap.put("avgvalue", "34.55");
        valuesMap.put("bidprice", "44.44");

        Iterator<String> iterator = valuesMap.keySet().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String name = iterator.next().toString();

            String value = (String) valuesMap.get(name);

            if (name.equals("last")) {

                String result = "";

                double d = Double.parseDouble(value);

                if (d > 1) {
                    result = formatNumber(value, 2);
                } else {
                    result = formatNumber(value, 4);
                }

                System.out.println(result);
            }

        }

    }

    public static String formatNumber(String s, int decPts) {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);

        if (2 == decPts)
            return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.00").format(d);
        else if (0 == decPts)
            return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0").format(d);
        else if (3 == decPts)
            return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.000").format(d);
        else if (4 == decPts)
            return new DecimalFormat("0.0000").format(d);
        return String.valueOf(d);

    }

}
```

Comment: You could create a `Map<Integer, DecimalFormat>`.

Comment: The patterns are too long, `#,##0.00` is better - minor improvement :)

Answer (score 5):

You could create a `Map<Integer, DecimalFormat> formats` (or a `List<DecimalFormat>`, if you prefer). Then `formatNumber()` simply calls `formats.get(decPts)` to get the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `switch` sentence

```
switch (decPts) {
  case 0:
     return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0").format(d);
  case 2:
     ...

}
```

It helps tidy the code for this case. Anyway you would not be able to program in any language without using `ìf` or similar constructs.

Comment: Hmm Code-Guru's solution was able to not use if or similar constructs :)

Comment: A note: You don't need `break` after `return`.

Answer (score 1):

The logic you're implementing in the `formatNumber` method is the perfect candidate for a switch statement. Try

```
switch (decPts) {
    case 0:
        return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0").format(d);
        break;
    case 2:
        return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.00").format(d);
        break;
    ...
}
```

For more info see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

edit: Although SJuan76 beat me to it, and I like Code-Guru's idea better!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Code-Guru's answer.  You can use a map but to retain the same thread safety and default behavior the code becomes:

```
public class CustValues {
    private static final Map<Integer, String> FORMATS;
    static {
        Map<Integer, String> formats = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        formats.put( 0, "#,###,###,##0" );
        formats.put( 2, "#,###,###,##0.00" );
        formats.put( 3, "#,###,###,##0.000" );
        formats.put( 4, "0.0000" );

        FORMATS = Collections.unmodifiableMap( formats );
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Same as before....
    }

    public static String formatNumber(String s, int decPts) {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        String format = FORMATS.get(decPts);
        if( format != null ) {
            return new DecimalFormat(format).format(d);
        }
        return String.valueOf(d);
    }
}
```

You need to create a new DecimalFormat for each request instead of reusing it since it is not thread safe.  This also handles the cases where decPts is not 0, 2, 3, or 4.

Answer (score 1):

I have method as below:

```
public static String formatNumber(String s, int decPts) {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s);

    if (decPts >= 0 && decPts <= 4) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0");
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(decPts);
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(decPts);
        return df.format(d);
    }

    return String.valueOf(d);

}
```

Comment: In fact, it's better to declare `DecimalFormat df` as `private static final` variable of the class!

Answer (score 0):

Enums have the advantage of avoiding boxing and unboxing an integer that a map.get call would perform, while only creating the formatters you need one time.  Note, you can also could get rid of the second double parse:

```
enum DisplayFormat {
  CURRENCY(new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,#00.00")),
  SMALL_CURRENCY(new DecimalFormat("0.000"));

  private DecimalFormat f;

  public DisplayFormat(DecimalFormat f) {
    this.f = f;
  }

  public String format(double d) {
    return this.f.format(d);
}

// Usage:

if (name.equals("last")) {
  String result = "";

  double d = Double.parseDouble(value);

  if (d > 1) {
    result = DisplayFormat.SMALL_CURRENCY.format(d)
  } else {
    result = DisplayFormat.CURRENCY.format(d)
  }

  System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One really **inefficient**, but more *flexible* option would be to generate the format string based on decPts:

```
public static String formatNumber(String s, int decPts) {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s);

    final String baseFormat = "#,###,###,##0"; 
    // TODO: Use a StringBuilder
    String format = decPts==0 ? baseFormat : baseFormat + "."; 
    for (int i=0; i < decPts; i++) {
        format += "0"; 
    }

    return new DecimalFormat(format).format(d);
}
```

Again, this is a **bad idea** unless you need to show an arbitrary number of decimal points or can only determine the way to display the number at run-time, which probably isn't the case.